# How to use notification service extension in Cordova FCM

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, ios11, ios-extensions

I'm very new in ionic. I have tried many methods to use notification service extension but, it doesn't work. I have followed these tutorials:

1. https://github.com/CleverTap/CTNotificationService
2. https://github.com/infobip/mobile-messaging-sdk-ios/wiki/Notification-Service-Extension-for-Rich-Notifications-and-better-delivery-reporting-on-iOS-10#creating-a-new-notification-service-extension

What is the easiest way to use notification service extension in cordova FCM and how to use it?
could you guys help me please?

Comment: Use this plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm

Comment: Is this plugin has the same functions as notification service extension functions?

Comment: please go through documentation of this plugin and git repo for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actually I'm trying to auto increase badge number once notification received in ios. So, I saw some developer said the only solution is to use Notification Service Extension. Thats why I'm looking for its functions.

Comment: I'll go through and try this plugin, thank you again.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/badge

Comment: Hi @Najam Us Saqib, Can you please explain for me what is the different between using  `import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';` and `import { FCM } from 'cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/ionic/ngx';`

Comment: I'm using `import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';` with notification service extension but, still notification not increase. While if I try use `import { FCM } from 'cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/ionic/ngx';` notification not work at all and I get error.  Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Install latest Version and Import it with: `import { FCM } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/fcm/ngx';`